# Why am I getting errno 32: Broken Pipe error when connected to a public network?

Tags: python-3.x, network-programming

I am currently creating a network and whenever I try to connect my two devices on my school network the devices refuse to connect to each other. However I try the exact same program on my home network and it connects perfectly fine. I am not sure why the problem arises and I have looked all over the internet for a solution but I couldn't find any.

I initially thought the error was a result of the slow internet connection on my school network so I tried to incorporate a while loop around the parts that were responsible for connecting the client and server. The program was unable to connect after multiple attempts at trying to connect on my school network. The problem isn't with any of my code because I am able to run this on my home network perfectly fine with both devices being able to connect to the server.

Client Program:

```
class Network:
    def __init__(self):
        self.client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.server = 'Insert IPv4 Address Here'
        self.port = 5555
        self.addr = (self.server, self.port)

    def getServer(self):
        return self.server

    def make_Connection(self):
        try:
            self.client.connect(self.addr)  # Connect the client to the server
            return pickle.loads(self.client.recv(2048))  
        except socket.error as e:
            print(e)

    def send_and_receive(self, data):
        try:
            self.client.send(pickle.dumps(data))  
            return pickle.loads(self.client.recv(2048))  
        except socket.error as e:
            print(e)


### --- Client --- ###
network = Network()
output = network.Make_Connection()
print(output)
output= network.send_and_receive('Hello World')
print(output)
```

Server Program:

```
from _thread import *
import socket
import pickle

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
try:
    s.bind(('', 5555))
except socket.error as e:
    print(e)

s.listen(2)

# functions #
def ThreatedClient(conn, player):
    conn.send(pickle.dumps('Connection Established'))
    while True:
        try:
            new_data = pickle.loads(conn.recv(2048))  
            if not new_data:
                print('Disconnected...')
                break
            else:
                if player == 0:
                    reply = pickle.dumps('This is Player 1') 
                else:
                    reply = pickle.dumps('This is Player 2')

            conn.sendall(reply)  # Send reply to clients
        except:
            break

    print('Connection Lost ... ')
    conn.close()

### --- Thread Starts Here --- ###
current_player = 0
while True:
    c, address = s.accept()  # Accepts connection from client
    print('Connected to:', address)

    start_new_thread(ThreatedClient, (c, current_player))
    current_player += 1
```

In the server the expected output should be:

```
Connected to: ('IPv4 Address', Port)
```

In the client the expected output should be:

```
Connection Established
This is Player 1
```

for player 1 and:

```
Connection Established
This is Player 2
```

for player 2.

When I run the same program on my school network the output is errno 32: Broken Pipe

Comment: What IP addresses are you using on the school network?  What is the normal range?  Do they have firewalls between your devices?  If both of your devices are wireless, then more than likely they have disabled peer to peer traffic on their WAPs.  I don't think this is a code problem, I think it's a networking problem.